# How does the solid rocket booster jettison system work on an Atlas V?

Tags: srb, atlas-v, separation

Is safe booster separation (they call it "jettison") without recontact assured by separation motors, pushers, or what?

The [Juno Mission Overview](https://www.ulalaunch.com/docs/default-source/news-items/av_juno_mob.pdf) refers to "structural thrusters" but that means nothing to me. The term "structural thrusters" does not appear in the [Atlas V User's Guide](https://www.ulalaunch.com/docs/default-source/rockets/atlasvusersguide2010.pdf).

Comment: Couldn't find anything more precise than this: "The SRBs are [jettisoned by thrusters](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ulalaunch.com/docs/default-source/rockets/atlas400_cutaway.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjSxLytzs_mAhVJzTgGHQTXDxYQFjAQegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw2Q0GrJ-TkRqU-eydkF_UEP)  following a burn lasting approximately a minute and a half."

Comment: I don't see any obvious sep motor burn [in this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WfOOGRDlQVU).

Comment: @RussellBorogove Maybe they've got cold gas thrusters? at 0:38 there seems to be a gas plume right in the middle of the booster (although the camera angle is such that its sort of coinciding with the plume from the bottom of the rocket)